# Can Facebook Live Stream Plugin be used on site outside of Facebook?

Tags: facebook, stream, live

Does anyone out there have a working example of the Facebook live stream plugin
that exists on a NON facebook webpage (meaning one that isn't located in the facebook domain ie. a canvas app)?

Has anyone successfully managed to integrate the Facebook Live Stream plugin into their site?

I cannot successfully do this using the code given by facebook which is:

```
 <div id="fb-root" ></div>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=MYAPPID&amp;xfbml=1">
 </script><fb:live-stream event_app_id="MYAPPID" width="400" xid=""
  height="500" always_post_to_friends="false"></fb:live-stream>
```

Facebook has almost 0 documentation on this and whatever they do have is vague. I've searched forums regarding the issue but they are all full of people who can't get it to work and no decent solutions posted.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that I had "accept 3rd party cookies' turned off in my browser and the plugin needed to access these in order to work.